# Rails: Issue in adding alias name in rails sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

i am working on maintenance application.basically i have a method in my code which is called by multiple methods. This method basically forms sql query as shown below.

```
def filter_data
  data = Student.all
  data = data.where(:id => params[:id]) if params[:id]
  data = data.where(:roll_no => params[:roll_no]) if params[:roll_no]
  return data
end
```

i am using this method in many places in my application as shown below

```
def get_user_data
  data = filter_data
  data.pluck("sum(marks)")
end
```

Now the issue is that that i want to add inner join to "students" table inside `filter_data` method. Now since "marks" column is in both table i will have to add alias in "get_user_data" method as shown below.

```
data.pluck("sum(students.marks)")
```

Adding alias is not an issue but i will have to add alias throughout my application where `"filter_data"` method is used. This is very time consuming process and i want to avoid it. is there any way to tell active-record to use "xxx" as an alias name when alias is not present in sql query.

Please let me know if anyone has any solutions for this issue.

Comment: So you always want students `marks` only?

Comment: No.. its just an example..in real scenario there are many places in my application where i am using many column names present in both tables.(sometimes the columns are two . sometimes one and sometimes 10)

Answer (score 0):

you can put an alias in models as

```
# alias_attribute :new_column_name, :column_name_in_db
alias_attribute :model_name_marks, :marks
```

So, **probably** you should be able to pluck with new name without sql alias.

*Note*: Untested but worth a try..

Also, I think, `filter_data` method can be reduced to one query instead of multiple..

in `student.rb`

```
scope :filter_by_id, ->(id) { where(id: id) if id.present? }
scope :filter_by_roll_no, ->(roll_no) { where(roll_no: roll_no) if roll_no.present? }
```

then your method becomes,

```
def filter_data
  Student.filter_by_id(params[:id]).filter_by_roll_no(params[:roll_no])
end
```